# In a VC++ project in Visual Studio, how to I specify /EXPORT symbols?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-c++, linker

I have a makefile project that builds and links a DLL, using the command-line cl.exe compiler, which is included in the VC++ Express (free) tool.  I now want to convert that makefile project into a Visual Studio project.

The DLL is not actually C++; it's all written in C.

The DLL exports a small number of symbols, functions that are called by other programs that link to the DLL. I believe that in order to produce this DLL, I need to include an `/EXPORT:Foo` statement on the link command line, for each exported symbol.

How do I do the same in Visual Studio 2008?  How do I specify the linker options to export a specific, small set of functions from the DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the "Additional Options" in the linker "Command Line" property and add the options explicitly.

I think that most people use the `__declspec(dllexport)` attributes along with macros to make it more usable and to make the declspec a dllimport version in the headers for clients of the library.

Answer (score 4):

See the first couple of subsections of [Exporting from a DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8(VS.80).aspx), which says,

> You can export functions from a DLL
>   using two methods:
>
> Create a module definition (.def) file
>   and use the .def file when building
>   the DLL. Use this approach if you want
>   to export functions from your DLL by
>   ordinal rather than by name.
>
> Use the keyword __declspec(dllexport)
>   in the function's definition.

Answer (score 2):

or you can try:

```
cl /LD hellodll.cpp /link /EXPORT:func01 /EXPORT:func01
```

for functions that is not specified by `"_declspec(dllexport)"`

Comment: Right, but the question was how to do it within Visual Studio, not how to do it on the command line. In fact in my question I even stated that I could do it on the command line with the `/EXPORT` option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a GUI option for it, so you could just add it manually under Command Line under Linker in the project's Properties. I think most people use a DEF file for this, though.